# Replace "strings" with HTML code in contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, html

## Idea

I'm making a configuration editor for a game, and I want to replace some of the strings with HTML code tooltips that would summarize what the command does, such as **gravity** or **ammo**.

I've tried data.replace(replacet, replacew), both (replace this) and (replace with) being array of strings and no, its not working.

---

## JavaScript

```
    function updateStrings() {

        var replacet = "sv_cheats ";
        var replacew = "&nbsp;<mark>sv_cheats</mark>&nbsp;";

        var data = document.getElementById('data').innerHTML;

        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = data.replace(replacet, replacew);

    }

    document.addEventListener('onkeydown', document.getElementById('data'), updateStrings());
```

---

## Point

This code I'd say roughly works, but the caret position is set to 0 (beginning) on every key press as the JavaScript tries to append every character given at the first position which clearly is not supposed to be happening.

Question is are there any frameworks that do this automatically? I'd want something like in VS Code when if you hover over a function it tells you the parameters and such, something like that would be awesome to have!

Thanks!

Comment: replacet and replacew should be strings. you cannot use arrays. May be you can loop through the array and apply the replace
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @VinodSai Sure enough, sounds like the way to go but the problem is the caret changes position at every key press which clearly is not something to go with when you're developing an application that is going to be released. Makes sense of course. No one would love to type these in reverse.